# Spam and Placement in the Store

Tags: android, google-play

According to **Spam and Placement in the Store** that comes under **Google Play Developer Program Policies**

**Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:**

1. Drive affiliate traffic to a website or
2. Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you
   (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to
   do so)

I wanted to know

- if I can provide links in my Android App to Youtube, Google Search,
  Wikipedia and Facebook Fan page that I administer?
- According to point number 2. I cannot provide a webview for Youtube,
  Google Search and Wikipedia because I don't own or administer them
  but can I provide a webview for my Facebook fan page that I administer?

My App has got some photos of a celebrity. According the points below, I don't own them.

**Ask permission to use copyrighted work**—If you want to use another party's copyrighted work in your app, you should ask for permission from the work's creator or copyright owner and include appropriate copyright attribution.

I wanted to know how can I ask for their permission and who to ask for? as they are all over the web available for free. How do I make them copy right protected.

I find these points confusing. I'd be grateful if someone can explain them to me. My App got suspended twice. I don't know how to make things right. Please help.

Comment: What is the primary function of the app?

Comment: @weston It is basically an App version of my Facebook Fan Page.

Comment: Well this app seems to be  a kind of webcentric **you**: **You** on the Tube, **you** on FaceBook, **you** on Google, ... everywhere **you**!! Ain't you a bit **narcissist**?

Comment: @weston :P. Youtube, Wikipedia, Google Search, Fan Page is all about that celebrity. Could you please explain to me the points above in general in order for me to avoid these problems in future? Thanks

Comment: I didn't say that, Der Golem did. But I guess google don't want to have the market place full of apps that are just weakened version of other apps, like the facebook app, the you tube app etc. They are saying your app must have a purpose other than acting like a bookmark.

Comment: @weston. I am sorry for my previous comment :P. I am not making use of Apps. They take to the link via Chrome. Am I allowed to provide links to these websites? Because e-g videos take a lot of space so I provide links to youtube for them and some things that are easily found on web, I didn't include them in my App instead have provided links to a respective website.

Comment: Well, Heidi, if you are such a celebrity, you should publish an app such as a game about you: a Trivia, a Fun and Facts, a Did you know... or an encyclopedia about you. You'd be allowed to do this for your countless fans.

Comment: @DerGolem Stretching the joke a little now. Apart from the ambiguous phrase "my Facebook fan page", I fail to see how you read into this question that Heidi **was** the celeb.

Comment: NOO I am not a celebrity and I am Heidi a totally unknown person :D . OK that page is about a celebrity who I am (and many others) a fan of. Please help me understand these laws, in general, forget about the page. I'd be grateful.

Comment: First, you should **contact** your celebrity and ask his/her **permission**. Discuss with them if they **agree** and what they allow you to use for their image. And if they can contribute with informations or whatever. After all, it's **free marketing**, for them.